# What is the equivalent of the Mapper.cleanup() method in the old Hadoop API?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to measure the time that each Map task takes from the time it begins until it ends. The way I do this is that I start a timer in the setup() function, and I output the timer in the cleanup() function. The issue now is that I am trying to do the same thing but for the old Hadoop API, but there seems to be nothing equivalent to cleanup()

Comment: Also, is there a way I can get the Hadoop examples in the new API?

Comment: examples are present under "/HADOOP_HOME/src/examples/org/apache/hadoop/examples"

Answer (score 0):

You might find [OutputCommiter.commitJob](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/OutputCommitter.html) useful. But why do you want to use the older API. New one is much cleaner.

Comment: it is because the Hadoop examples already use the old API. I would like to work on them without rewriting them from scratch. I agree though that the new API is much better. Thanks

Comment: yeah..some of them use the older API, but i would still suggest to use the new API. You can never guarantee when the they are going to remove all the depricated stuff. writing code is just 1 time activity, but trust me changing an already running code is really the bigger pain.

Answer (score 0):

In the old API, you need to override the `java.io.Closeable.close()` method. On a side note, you can get the map task execution times from the job tracker.